# What circumstances could lead to the creation of numerous pan-Celtic macronations?

Tags: society, politics, geopolitics

***TDLR: After peace and stability in the West goes to hell, the UN collapses, and nationalism arises. Ireland and Scotland return to being fully Celtic again while England becomes a 3rd world country wracked by civil wars that the Irish, Scottish, Welsh and Cornish invade to make into a Cornish and Welsh-speaking nation. This event, in turn, prompts a wave of pan-Celtism across Europe in countries where Celts once lived and the creation of Celtic macronations speaking Celtic conlangs arise.***

***Why does this happen?***

In the distant future, worsening racial relations and mass immigration have sparked significant instability, the UN's collapse and the rise of right-wing nationalist governments in the West. The few *"winners"* of this contest were Ireland and Scotland, which kept a good chunk of their infrastructures intact and enacted a successful and aggressive *"re-celticisation"* that saw Irish and Scottish Gaelic becoming dominant languages again.

Yet, the Irish and Scottish governments didn't rest on their laurels as they had developed a *"never again"* mindset deeming their nearest neighbour, England, as *"an existential threat to Celtism"* due to its imperialist history. With England degraded into a 3rd world country after fighting its constant civil wars, Ireland and Scotland launched a joint invasion of England with help from Welsh and Cornish guerrillas. The invasion succeeded, and England became the *Lloegyr Commonwealth*, a Welsh and Cornish-speaking nation under the Irish and Scottish rationale of:

*"We almost had our languages and cultures destroyed under English imperialism. Now, you'll know what it's like to have your language and culture destroyed under Celtic imperialism!"*

But, while the international reaction to the Scot-Irish-Welsh-Cornish victory over England and *Lloegyr Commonwealth's* creation, consisted mixture of panic and amazement, no-one knew what would come next. In a wave of pan-Celticism that would become known as the *"Second Celtic Revival"*, where many Celtic micronations named after various Celtic clans and speaking languages reconstructed from historical Celtic languages would pop up across Europe in countries with a historical pre-Roman Celtic presence. At first, such a trend was viewed with mild amusement and then annoyance as more of these micronations formed and became macronations, which led to the formation of the United Celtic Coalition, an alliance headed by Ireland, Lloegyr, Scotland, Brittany, and the Isle of Man.

But the question is: ***why and how would something like this happen? Especially in nations that haven't even  been Celtic for millennium?***

Comment: This is a very broad and open ended question where you're effectively asking us to come up with our own stories about what would have to inevitably be a complicated series of geopolitical events.  To quote from our help center "if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers, it's probably too broad for our format". As written your question meets both those criterial .

Comment: ". . . Celtic micronations named after various Celtic clans and speaking languages reconstructed from historical Celtic languages . . ." Is this your definition of a Celtic Nation or do you have something else in mind?

Comment: This isn't entirely implausible as a scenario. Please see https://www.theonion.com/society-for-creative-anachronism-seizes-control-of-russ-1819565189 for details.

Comment: Now, if you'd added the [tag:magic] tag, then it'd be because of the discovery that Celtic blooded people can use it and it's the language of spells....

Comment: Welcome Tiarnaard, I’m sorry this really doesn’t fit the format of this site. We do have a chat area for brainstorming and then, when you get a focussed problem, we can tackle it. It seems an interesting topic, however unsuitable. Vote to close.

Comment: Will Nova Scotia and Patagonia fit into this in any way?

Answer (score 6):

### "Celtic" ?

*"Especially in nations that haven't even been Celtic for millennium?"*. Frankly, your Scots, Irish and Welsh haven't been "Celtic" either, for at least a thousand years (more like 2000 years). The spread of Gaelic in Scotland was imported from Ireland in the 5th-6th century, only a few islands remain where people speak Gaelic. Scottish nationalists in your world would probably prefer "Pict" warrior culture, speak English and go to war with these "Celts".

Being "Celtic" is part of the nationalist mythology and cultural heritage, not real world. War is real world activity. The Germans have shown in WW-II you can't impose ancient foreign mythology on occupied countries.

Why would Welsh, Irish and Scots want to impose *Gaelic language* in the first place ? When nationalism rises everywhere, it will rise in England as well. After conquering England, your "modern Celts" would face resistance from "modern Anglosaxons". The more cultural demands an occupier puts, the fiercer the resistance will be !

Comment: If anything, the resulting government structure would likely be Welsh speaking if only because Welsh is so much healthier a language and is spoken more broadly.

Comment: @elemtilas I had to look that up.. I've assumed this was about Gaelic, but I now wonder if the opener knows "Lloegyr" is a Welsh word, not Gaelic. Also found some comments on Quora, that Gaelic and Welsh are phonetically related, but there's hardly any word similar. That would point to a common Celt origin that may originate in Roman times, ref https://www.quora.com/How-does-the-Welsh-language-compare-to-Gaelic ... the earlier La Tène / Hallstadt Celt language is unknown.

Comment: All the Celtic languages are related, deriving from Proto-Celtic maybe 3000 to 3500 years ago. Celtic is also related to Italic (from which derive Latin and its Romance descendants). We have very little in the way of ancient Celtic textual evidence -- a few Gaulish inscriptions -- while literature in what we'd call the earliest forms of recognisably "modern" Celtic languages survive from the 4th century (Ireland) and 5th century (Wales). Scottish Gaelic and Cornish literature don't appear until the 1100s and 1500s or so.

Answer (score 2):

There is little I can imagine that would fit the bill. Allow me to explain why.

## First

Europe's history is rife with wars (civil and multinational) and plagues and famines and political collapses and more. And yet there are so many different cultures and languages.

- So the only possibility would be a series of events so bad that the vast majority of Europe's population dies off. Think on a scale that would make the black death look like a picnic.

## Second

Just as Ireland and Scotland value their Celtic roots, the French feel the same about their Gaul and Frankish roots. While it can be argued that they were Celts first, and that the Gaul sprang up from their Celtic ancestors, that was the unifying aspect of Europe pre-Roman empire. Gauls and Franks are uniquely French, and thus the French would place more emphasis on such.

This holds true for Germanic peoples. For Slavs. For the Rus. For the Romani. For every single people demographic within Europe.

- You would need either an authoritarian dictator to force it down their throats, which they will rebel against as they historically always have. Or you'd need a reason so thorough why English is being replaced as the 'international lingua franca' that no one can logically argue against it.

## Third

Any singular 'pure blood' group is no longer the only demographic within that country's borders. While that might arguably be the case a thousand years ago, you have a thriving non-native population in each country now.

Why would a Chinese-Spanish population agree to learn Gaelic, when they already need to speak Chinese and Spanish and arguably English already? Why would the Mongolian-German population agree? Why would the Nigerian-French population agree? Why would the Argentinian-Dutch population?

These are groups that maintain their own culture in a supposedly foreign land. Why would the 'invading' Celtic culture and language be any different?

- You'd need to change all levels of formal education to enforce Gaelic is the language to teach, and that requires teachers that speak it fluently and can teach it to Gaelic as a second language students.

## Fourth

You'd need a reason why Ireland and Scotland would want to dominate the European landscape. Nationalism is one thing, imperialism and colonialism are quite another. Countries that have had their culture almost wiped out have an innate dislike for seeing others share their fate.

- Even if the 'leader supreme' of both nations want it, they'd need a robust propaganda campaign to convince their population not to fight them on this. And keep in mind that the native population would need to teach those other nations the culture/language, so their cooperation is essential. Let alone keeping the reins of power in the leader supreme's paws. And take the current Russian rejection of the Ukrainian invasion--even under a dictator like Putin, there's no guarantee the people will support this expansionist agenda if they hate it more than they fear the leader.

## Conclusion

You'd have to take a multi-generational approach to this, spreading the changes over decades if not centuries.

You'd need something that affects every major European power other than Ireland and Scotland enough to weaken them militarily, politically, and economically.

You'd need to cover up the cultural genocides of the Irish and Scots to convince their populace they shouldn't rebel against it.

You'd need inarguable reasons why non-native citizens would go along with it as opposed to returning to their country of origin.

And you'd need something the international community wouldn't take the non-Gaelic side of.

There is nothing I can think of that fits these criteria. So it's either handwaving it all away, which I despise, or you take the bulletpoints I offered and craft something along those lines.

Comment: Don't forget that the Franks were originally a Germanic tribe that invaded that area, not Celtic.

Comment: @DavidR Can't forget what you didn't know.

Comment: And the people of Normandy were refugees from Norwegian wars in the early 900's who quickly assimilated.

Answer (score 2):

**Europe and England have been devastated.**

[image: nuke map]

[source](https://www.quora.com/Why-could-a-nuclear-war-cause-our-extinction-when-the-thousands-of-nuclear-bombs-humanity-has-detonated-so-far-havent-done-so-yet)

In the nuclear exchange, the north of Scotland was relatively spared and west Ireland did ok.  England is pretty much toast as is France and Germany.  Wales too, unfortunately for those wanting more of the letter L.

After the apocalypse, the Scottish leader that arose had some unusual ideas and an unusual load of charisma.  And he was also unusually aggressive.  The Irish did not need conquering as they signed on for his program once he showed up.

The Spanish did need some conquering and this Scottish / Irish group got a taste for it.  Once they saw what it was all about, the Spanish were good with it too.  The NeoCeltic program spread through Europe.  Most places were happy to have someone show up who did not just want to cough up blood on them - a person with aspirations to build back civilization was a welcome sight, even if the civilization built was some romanticized past Celtic heyday.  A plan is better than no plan and aside from his halfbaked cultural aspirations (or perhaps because of them) this Highlander has good ideas about government.

Comment: As a side note: Although Gaelic may be very uncommon in Spain today, they were a part of the Celtic cultural zone.  So, with the right propaganda, they could be sold on this being a sort of Renaissance for them as well.

Comment: *Most places were happy to have someone show up who did not just want to cough up blood on them* --- Best line I've seen in WB in a while!

Answer (score 2):

### Leperchauns

With the endless profusion of cameras, spy satellites, traffic cameras, beamformed terahertz networks, it was bound to happen.  *Somebody finally proved leperchauns were real*.  My apologies for using American spelling. :)  With their pots of gold proved to be real, and brought to heel, the leperchauns were forced to make a *deal*:  to teach the world some words of magic.

But all the magic is in Celtic, and only a True Celtic can cast it.

From Ireland to Scotland, from America to Russia, among Peruvian native peoples and the Bongo of South Sudan - *everywhere*, people are rediscovering their Celtic roots, real or imagined, and practicing the spells they downloaded off the internet.  Perhaps they are most often successful in the Celts' native Austria *(yes, look it up)*, but there is a little Irish in everyone.

Sometimes they work.  From fertile fields to rat armies, the world answers the call of the bold.  And so all over the world, new wizards are rising up to push aside the crooks, chiselers, and fintech people who thought they were in charge.  You have not *lived* until you've dined on the frog legs of a patent troll.  Behind the antlered standard of Cernunnos, proud new tribes sporting caubeen and shillelagh rise armed to restore the earth and the wild.

Download the text files, practice how to pronounce O’Maoldhomhnaigh, and be ready to pay a premium for quality four leaf clover.  *GLORY* awaits you!

Answer (score 1):

### Language Spreads for Practical Reasons much Faster than Imposed Ones

The number one reason for a language to spread quickly is because someone has a thing that is so important to other people that they WANT to learn their language to be able to negotiate for, or use it.  So if you want Celtic to be spoken outside of Lloegyr, it means that the this new nation has something very important that the rest of the world wants a part of.

One solution would be to make Lloegyr the pioneers of some Unobtanium or a McGuffin Tech that forces the rest of the world to trade with them or be left behind.

Another way you could go is to treat Lloegyr as a sort of preserver civilization.  Instead of just having Europe collapse, it could have been a global event.  The whole world got caught up in some very nasty wars.  Here in the info age, the biggest targets of military aggression are the electric grid, communications networks, and data centers.  So imagine that nearly all of infrastructure of the internet gets wiped out leaving vast amounts of human information destroyed or otherwise inaccessible.  But somewhere in Ireland, perhaps there are data centers used to store all the Gaelic translations of nearly every website in the world. Nearly no one speaks Gaelic; so, these data center were deemed too unimportant to destroy. But when the fighting is all done, it turns out that Ireland not only has the most complete record of remaining human knowledge, but it is in Gaelic.  It also turns out all that fancy translation software that companies like Google has been developing for the past 20+ years were also stored and backed up in now destroyed data centers; so, just converting the Gaelic translations of the internet back to other languages is not so easy as it once was.  As various factions try to rebuilt the internet, most find they are starting at square 1, or only have bits and pieces of what they need, but the Lloegyrs have everything they need to restore most human knowledge. So, with the internet mostly back up, but only in Gaelic, there would be a huge impetus for people across the world to learn Gaelic so that they can use the best version of the restored internet there is.